# How to change the text color in rows of TableView?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to update row background color and text in tableview. But i am able to update only background colour. But i am not able to update text color using -fx-text-fill. Could someone help.

```
@FXML
private void initialize(){
 tablename.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<ClassName>()
    {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(ClassName item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null)
            {
                setText(null);
                setStyle("");
            }
            else
            {
               if (item.gettest().equals("a") {
                 setStyle("-fx-background-color: #38ee00; -fx-text-fill: green;");
                }
               if (item.gettest().equals("b") {
                 setStyle("-fx-background-color: #efe939; -fx-text-fill: red;");
                }
              }
          }
      });

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Also, there have been several QAs recently with the exact same (or very similar) requirement, so please search and compare to your context :)

Comment: I have searched, before posting the question. But, unfortunately i have not found a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TableView` colors the background of it's rows from `modena.css` which is why you can override this property using inline style. The `-fx-text-fill` property is set for the `TableCell`s though and therefore the values inherited from the `TableRow` are not used.

I recommend using a CSS stylesheet yourself and applying a pseudoclass to the rows

```
final PseudoClass green = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("green");
tablename.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<ClassName>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(ClassName item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        boolean gr = (item != null) && item.gettest().equals("a");
        pseudoClassStateChanged(green, gr); 
    }
});
```

CSS Stylesheet (needs to be applied to the `TableView`, an ancestor or the scene)

```css
.table-row-cell:filled {
    -fx-background-color: #efe939;
}

.table-row-cell:filled:green {
    -fx-background-color: #38ee00;
}

.table-row-cell:filled .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}

.table-row-cell:filled:green .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firts you need to get the current ROW :

```
 TableRow<CallLogs> currentRow = getTableRow();
```

After that you can set the colors as you are doing, but in the currentRow:

```
          if (item.gettest().equals("a") {
             currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #38ee00; -fx-text-fill: green;");
            }
           if (item.gettest().equals("b") {
              currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #efe939; -fx-text-fill: red;");
            }
```